# Running a Python script on CMD opens Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to run a Python script, instead of running it, Visual Studio pops open with the script. I initially thought that the CMD is not hitting the right interpreter. I checked the PATH and it was set correctly. I am using Python 3.6 installed with Anaconda on a Windows system.

Has anyone else experienced this before?

Comment: you wrongly associated the .py extension to visual studio. Reinstalling/repairing python should fix the problem.

Comment: I thought so too. How do I repair it? I really don't want a re-install

Comment: I've answered such a question in the past. the link indicates how to restore the registry without reinstalling.